# Latest build not found while downloading latest version of build artifact in Azure DevOps build definition

Tags: azure-devops

We are using the Download Build Artifacts task to download the latest build artifacts, however, we get the following error **"Latest build not found"** when the task is executed.

The same task succeeds when the "Specific version" option is selected under Build version to download instead of "Latest Build"

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you downloading build artifacts from a different pipeline than the one you have added to your release pipeline?

Comment: Maybe the latest build hasn't published artifacts?

Comment: @JoshGust The latest build has published the artifacts. To answer your first question, we are trying to download the build artifact of  "Build Definition 1" in "Build Definition 2"

Comment: Can you add some info from the logs of the build and a screen shot of the build task and its configuration? I'm not able to reproduce that at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Artifacts task checks for successful builds and not partially successful build. Hence the error "Latest build not found", as the build definition only had partially successful builds.

I was expecting the task to download artifacts from the partially successful build, which led to the error.

Resolution: Had to fix the build to be successful rather than being partially successful to download the required build artifacts from another build definition.